# Regular Expression for phrases starting with TO

Tags: regex

I am pretty  new to Regular Expression. I want to write a regular expression to get the TO Followed by the rest of it after each new line. I tried to use this but doesn't work properly. 
^TO\n?\s?[A-Za-z0-9]*\n?[A-Za-z0-9]*
It only highlights properly the TO W11 which all are in one line. Highlights only TO from first data and the 3rd data only highlights the first line. Basically it doesn't read the new lines.
Some of my data looks like this:

```
 TO
 EXTERNAL
 TRAVERSE

 TO W11

 TO CONTROL
 TRAVERSE
```

I would appreciate if anybody can help me.

Comment: "I tried to use this but didn't work out." How didn't it work? Did it not match anything? Have you tried online regex tester tools like http://regexpal.com/ ?

Comment: Yes it didn't match anything

Comment: `TO.*(?!TO)` Use a negative lookahead to stop at the next TO

Comment: `TO.*(?!TO\s)` to avoid stopping inside a word. Replace newlines with spaces would work better. `TO\s.*(?!TO\s)`

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you use a multiline regex:

```
var options = RegexOptions.MultiLine;

foreach (Match match in Regex.Matches(input, pattern, options))
...
```

More at: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yd1hzczs(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your pattern isn't matching because the start of the string is really a space and not the T character.  Also, `[A-Za-z0-9]` matches only one character, and you want the whole word.  I used the `+` to denote that I want one or more matches of those characters.

```
(TO\n?\s?[A-Za-z0-9]+)
```

This regex matches "TO EXTERNAL", "TO W11" and "TO CONTROL".  Be sure to use the global modifier so that you get all matches, not just the first one.

Comment: @ToastyMallows oops, didn't notice the `^` in his question!

Comment: @JuliánUrbano this answer removed the ^ from the front, allowing it to ignore the leading space

Comment: @user603948 I updated my answer. I moved the `(` to the beginning of the regex so that it includes `TO`.  Now this matches "TO EXTERNAL", "TO W11", "TO CONTROL".  See: http://regex101.com/r/rX5lD9

Comment: @user603948 Can you please update your question to include the relevant C# code you're using?

Comment: I'm using DataPrep to write the expressions & then use SDI to see my matches.

Comment: Is there any reason why you're not just using the built-in C# Regex library?  The link @JohnGibb posted in his answer has a lot of detailed examples.